# Ruby on Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

Hello i am a new in ROR and i have a problem with routing. My route  is  that 
  `http://localhost:3000/keys/pass.9` and i want to be like  `http://localhost:3000/keys/9/pass`

Look my routes :

```
resources :keys , only: [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update, :index]  do
collection do
  delete 'destroy_multiple'
  get  'pass'
end
```

end

the controller:

```
class  KeysController < ApplicationController

   def pass
     Key.find(params[:id]).update_attribute(:passwrod,SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 )
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
     end
 end
```

and the view:

```
  <div class="center hero-unit">
      <h1>Listing keys</h1>
       <%= form_tag destroy_multiple_keys_path, method: :delete do %>
          <table>
           <thead>
           <tr>
              <th></th>
             <th>Url</th>
           <th>Username</th>
          <th>Passwrod</th>
         <th>Category</th>
           </tr>
        </thead>
   <tbody>

    <div>
     <% for key in @keys %>
       <% if key.book.name == @book %>
       <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "key_ids[]", key.id %></td>
    <td><%=key.url %></td>
    <td><%=key.username %></td>
    <td><%=key.passwrod %></td>
    <td><%=key.category %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit',edit_key_path(key) %></td>
    <td> <%= link_to 'Change password', pass_keys_path(key)  %> </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
  <td> <input  type="button" value="check all"    onclick="$(this.form).getInputs('checkbox').each(function (elem) {elem.checked = true;});" /> </td>

  </tr>

</div>
```

```
  <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %>
   <% end %>
```

```
 <%= link_to 'New Key', new_key_path %>
 <%= link_to 'Back',  books_path %>
  </div>
```

and i get that error now :

Couldn't find Key without an ID

Comment: `member do
  get  'pass'
end`

For that you want a member route, not a collection

Comment: @user3438570 use member in routes ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the routes as

```
resources :keys , only: [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update, :index]  do
  collection do
    delete 'destroy_multiple'
  end
  member do
    get  'pass'
  end
end
```

Comment: thx!! that worked. i will put it as the solve in a few minutes.